# Getting all children on same level of binary tree

Tags: java, tree, iterator, treenode

I want to display all children on the same level of tree. So if I've got a tree like this:

```
            A
   B        C        D
 E   F    G   H    I   J
```

for example, level 3 would return E, F, G, H, I and J nodes. I have a method inside `TreeNode` class, that returns all children of given node, so I thought about doing something like this:

```
static Collection<ITreeNode<IProduct>> getOnLevel(ITree<IProduct> tree, int level)
{
    Collection<ITreeNode<IProduct>> temp;
    int i;
    Iterator<ITreeNode<IProduct>> iterator = tree.getRoot().getChildren().iterator();
    for(i=0; i<=(level); i++) 
    {       
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {                   
            ITreeNode<IProduct> elem = iterator.next();
            if(i == (level)) 
            {
                temp = elem.getChildren();
                return temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return tree.getRoot().getChildren(); 

}
```

but then I realized that I just iterate through first level children, so I probably have to do this somehow recursively? 
Thanks in advance, Amar!

Comment: Do a BFS traversal of the tree.

Comment: @NiVeR yes I understand concept of BFS traversal on binary tree, but how would it look like if tree can have multiple children, not just two? I can easily call same function two times recursively if it was a binary tree, but how do I do it if there is possibility of more children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either do it recursively or with iterations, it's up to you.

I find recursive solution slightly easier to read. It would look like this:

```
static Collection<ITreeNode<IProduct>> getOnLevel(
    ITree<IProduct> tree
,   int desiredLevel
) {
    List<ITreeNode<IProduct>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    findOneLevel(tree.getRoot(), desiredLevel, 0, result);
    return result;
}

static void findOnLevel(
    ITreeNode<IProduct> node
,   int desiredLevel
,   int currentLevel
,   List<ITreeNode<IProduct>> result
) {
    if (currentLevel == desiredLevel) {
        result.add(node);
        return;
    }
    Iterator<ITreeNode<IProduct>> iterator = node.getChildren().iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
       findOnLevel(iterator.next(), desiredLevel, currentLevel+1, result);
    }
}
```

The approach is very simplistic: top-level method makes a list in which to store the result, and calls the recursive `findOnLevel`. Recursive method checks if we have reached the desired level, and adds the current node to the result if we did. Otherwise, we go through all children of the current node in a recursive invocation, passing `currentLevel+1` for the new current level.